# What are the connectors for GND and power supply on these RF LNAs?

Tags: rf, connector

What connectors are these? They seem to be widespread on LNAs.

[image]
Bonus question: is it a reliable connection? I am planning on using them on a large RC car so it is going to be shaken quite a lot.

Comment: Ground is just a turret terminal intended to be soldered to; I don't recognise the power one.

Comment: My guess is that the PWR connectors's middle pin is the supply connection while the larger cylinder around that pin is connected to GND. I would **measure that** to confirm. If that is indeed GND I would just solder wires (supply, GND) directly onto the PWR pin and simply ignore the GND connector. Since the PWR connector looks like brass to me, it should be easy to solder onto. The GND connector looks like a more difficult material to solder onto.

Comment: Also . that PWR connector looks like a "feedthrough" to me, it's not really a connector for which there is a plug, you're supposed to solder the wires directly onto it. I have seen the same on many other RF modules at work and there we also solder directly onto that feedthrough.

Comment: In pictures: https://www.tkolbehvila.com/details-about-nbspmiteq-rf-amplifier-36-42ghz-gain-30db-po-20dbm-amf3f0360424020p-p-61849.htm ;  https://www.tkolbehvila.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=425445 . Regular solder should be okay.

Comment: THanks to all, don't hesitate to post answers :)